# Insert comma before the decimal dot exactly 1 space

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, awk, sed

i have a bunch of erratic strings, for example,

`8000.000.189065200.059420490.024467260.126043470.189065200.129982320.024467260.059420490.19806830`

and would like to fix it using preferably `sed`, but `awk` is also welcome. what i want is fairly simple: insert a `,` before `.` exactly 1 spaces, so that the string can become

`8000.00,0.18906520,0.05942049,0.02446726,0.12604347,0.18906520,0.12998232,0.02446726,0.05942049,0.19806830`

you can tell that somebody makes a mistake by printing decimal numbers continuously without breaking it (actually it was me). luckily we only have between 0 and 1 decimals, so that makes a lot of things easier.

the question is: how can i do so?

thanks a lot for the kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following POSIX-compliant `sed` command inserts a `,` before *every* occurrence of `0.`, then removes the *first* occurrence of `,` to yield the desired output:

```
$ sed 's/0\./,&/g; s/,//' <<<'8000.000.189065200.059420490.024467260.126043470.189065200.129982320.024467260.059420490.19806830'
8000.00,0.18906520,0.05942049,0.02446726,0.12604347,0.18906520,0.12998232,0.02446726,0.05942049,0.19806830
```

Note:

- If you have *GNU* `sed`, [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40986938/45375) offers a simpler solution.
- For numbers not starting with `0.`, there is no unambiguous solution to this problem, except if the assumption is - as appears to be the case in the question - that only the *first* number on each line is a number >= 1 with decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

with GNU `sed`

```
echo 8000.000.189065200.059420490.024467260.126043470.189065200.129982320.024467260.059420490.19806830 | 
sed 's/0\./,&/2g' 

8000.00,0.18906520,0.05942049,0.02446726,0.12604347,0.18906520,0.12998232,0.02446726,0.05942049,0.19806830
```

`2g` will skip the first match and do the rest

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the pattern that there's a number, followed by a period, followed by 2 numbers?  Would the following work?

```
ian@simbian:~/t1$ cat t
8000.000.189065200.059420490.024467260.126043470.189065200.129982320.024467260.059420490.19806830

ian@simbian:~/t1$ sed 's/\([0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\)/\1,/g' t
8000.00,0.18,9065200.05,9420490.02,4467260.12,6043470.18,9065200.12,9982320.02,4467260.05,9420490.19,806830
```